# How to write an ebpf/xdp program to drop TCP packets containing a certain byte pattern?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I'm trying force the retransmission of certain TCP packet to test some feature.

I would like to drop RX TCP packets (dst port 4420) whose payload is all zeros except for the last 4 bytes which should have at least a non-null byte.

Unfortunately I cannot get around the eBPF verifier :(
I'm trying to compromise with "starts with at least 50 zero bytes followed by a non-zero byte" but still no luck.

```c
#define KBUILD_MODNAME "xdp_nvme_drop"
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/if_vlan.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/ipv6.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>
#include "../common/parsing_helpers.h"

static inline int parse_ipv4(void *data, uint64_t nh_off, void *data_end) {
        struct iphdr *iph = data + nh_off;

        if (data + nh_off + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end)
                return 0;
        return iph->protocol;
}

static inline int parse_ipv6(void *data, uint64_t nh_off, void *data_end) {
        struct ipv6hdr *ip6h = data + nh_off;

        if (data + nh_off + sizeof(struct ipv6hdr) > data_end)
                return 0;
        return ip6h->nexthdr;
}

//static uint64_t zeroes[1024];

SEC("xdp")
int nvme_drop(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
        void* data_end = (void*)(long)ctx->data_end;
        void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;
        uint64_t total = data_end-data;
        struct ethhdr *eth = data;
        uint16_t h_proto;
        uint32_t cur = 0;
        struct tcphdr *tcph;
        uint32_t i;
        int nbzeros = 0;
        bool found = 0;
        cur = sizeof(*eth);

        if (data + cur  > data_end)
                return XDP_PASS;

        h_proto = eth->h_proto;
        if (h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP)) {
                h_proto = parse_ipv4(data, cur, data_end);
                cur += sizeof(struct iphdr);
        } else if (h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IPV6)) {
                h_proto = parse_ipv6(data, cur, data_end);
                cur += sizeof(struct ipv6hdr);
        } else {
                return XDP_PASS;
        }

        if (cur > 100)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (h_proto != IPPROTO_TCP)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (data + cur + sizeof(*tcph) > data_end)
                return XDP_PASS;

        tcph = data + cur;
        if (tcph->doff > 10)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (data + cur + tcph->doff * 4 > data_end)
                return XDP_PASS;

        cur += tcph->doff * 4;
        
        if (tcph->dest != 4420)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (cur > total || cur > 100)
                return XDP_PASS;

        nbzeros = 0;
        for (i = cur; data+i < data_end; i++) {
                if (*((uint8_t*)(data+i)) == 0 && !found) {
                        nbzeros++;
                } else {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                }

        }

        if (found && nbzeros > 50) {
                bpf_printk("found nvme pdu tail seq=%u\n", bpf_ntohs(tcph->seq));
        }
        return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

Verifier output:

```
Validating nvme_drop() func#0...
0: R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;
0: (61) r2 = *(u32 *)(r1 +0)          ; R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R2_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0)
; void* data_end = (void*)(long)ctx->data_end;
1: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r1 +4)          ; R1_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0)
; if (data + cur  > data_end)
2: (bf) r3 = r2                       ; R2_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0)
3: (07) r3 += 14                      ; R3_w=pkt(off=14,r=0,imm=0)
; if (data + cur  > data_end)
4: (2d) if r3 > r1 goto pc+12         ; R1_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(off=14,r=14,imm=0)
; h_proto = eth->h_proto;
5: (71) r4 = *(u8 *)(r2 +12)          ; R2_w=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0) R4_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff))
6: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r2 +13)          ; R2_w=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0) R3_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff))
7: (67) r3 <<= 8                      ; R3_w=scalar(umax=65280,var_off=(0x0; 0xff00))
8: (4f) r3 |= r4                      ; R3_w=scalar() R4_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff))
; if (h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP)) {
9: (15) if r3 == 0xdd86 goto pc+9     ; R3_w=scalar()
10: (55) if r3 != 0x8 goto pc+6       ; R3=8
11: (b7) r3 = 34                      ; R3_w=34
12: (b7) r4 = 23                      ; R4_w=23
; if (data + nh_off + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end)
13: (bf) r5 = r2                      ; R2=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0) R5_w=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0)
14: (07) r5 += 34                     ; R5_w=pkt(off=34,r=14,imm=0)
; if (data + nh_off + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end)
15: (2d) if r5 > r1 goto pc+1         ; R1=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R5_w=pkt(off=34,r=34,imm=0)
16: (05) goto pc+7
;
24: (bf) r5 = r2                      ; R2=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0) R5_w=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0)
25: (0f) r5 += r4                     ; R4_w=P23 R5_w=pkt(off=23,r=34,imm=0)
26: (71) r4 = *(u8 *)(r5 +0)          ; R4=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R5=pkt(off=23,r=34,imm=0)
; if (h_proto != IPPROTO_TCP)
27: (55) if r4 != 0x6 goto pc-11      ; R4=6
; if (data + cur + sizeof(*tcph) > data_end)
28: (bf) r4 = r2                      ; R2=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0) R4_w=pkt(off=0,r=34,imm=0)
29: (0f) r4 += r3                     ; R3=P34 R4_w=pkt(off=34,r=34,imm=0)
; if (data + cur + sizeof(*tcph) > data_end)
30: (bf) r5 = r4                      ; R4_w=pkt(off=34,r=34,imm=0) R5_w=pkt(off=34,r=34,imm=0)
31: (07) r5 += 20                     ; R5_w=pkt(off=54,r=34,imm=0)
; if (data + cur + sizeof(*tcph) > data_end)
32: (2d) if r5 > r1 goto pc-16        ; R1=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R5_w=pkt(off=54,r=54,imm=0)
; if (tcph->doff > 10)
33: (69) r5 = *(u16 *)(r4 +12)        ; R4_w=pkt(off=34,r=54,imm=0) R5_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
34: (77) r5 >>= 4                     ; R5_w=scalar(umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
35: (57) r5 &= 15                     ; R5=scalar(umax=15,var_off=(0x0; 0xf))
; if (tcph->doff > 10)
36: (25) if r5 > 0xa goto pc-20       ; R5=scalar(umax=10,var_off=(0x0; 0xf))
; if (data + cur + tcph->doff * 4 > data_end)
37: (67) r5 <<= 2                     ; R5_w=scalar(umax=40,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c))
; if (data + cur + tcph->doff * 4 > data_end)
38: (bf) r0 = r4                      ; R0_w=pkt(off=34,r=54,imm=0) R4=pkt(off=34,r=54,imm=0)
39: (0f) r0 += r5                     ; R0_w=pkt(id=1,off=34,r=0,umax=40,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c),s32_max=60,u32_max=60) R5_w=Pscalar(umax=40,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c))
; if (data + cur + tcph->doff * 4 > data_end)
40: (2d) if r0 > r1 goto pc-24        ; R0_w=pkt(id=1,off=34,r=34,umax=40,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c),s32_max=60,u32_max=60) R1=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0)
; if (tcph->dest != 4420)
41: (69) r0 = *(u16 *)(r4 +2)         ; R0_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R4=pkt(off=34,r=54,imm=0)
; if (tcph->dest != 4420)
42: (55) if r0 != 0x1144 goto pc-26   ; R0_w=4420
43: (bf) r0 = r1                      ; R0_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R1=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0)
44: (1f) r0 -= r2                     ; R0_w=scalar() R2=pkt(off=0,r=54,imm=0)
45: (bf) r6 = r3                      ; R3=P34 R6_w=P34
46: (0f) r6 += r5                     ; R5=Pscalar(umax=40,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6=Pscalar(umin=34,umax=74,var_off=(0x2; 0x7c))
47: (2d) if r6 > r0 goto pc-31        ; R0=scalar() R6=Pscalar(umin=34,umax=74,var_off=(0x2; 0x7c))
48: (bf) r0 = r2                      ; R0_w=pkt(off=0,r=54,imm=0) R2=pkt(off=0,r=54,imm=0)
49: (0f) r0 += r6                     ; R0_w=pkt(id=3,off=0,r=0,umin=34,umax=74,var_off=(0x2; 0x7c),s32_min=2,s32_max=126,u32_min=2,u32_max=126) R6=Pscalar(umin=34,umax=74,var_off=(0x2; 0x7c))
50: (3d) if r0 >= r1 goto pc-34       ; R0_w=pkt(id=3,off=0,r=0,umin=34,umax=74,var_off=(0x2; 0x7c),s32_min=2,s32_max=126,u32_min=2,u32_max=126) R1=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0)
; for (i = cur; data+i < data_end; i++) {
51: (0f) r3 += r5                     ; R3_w=Pscalar(umin=34,umax=74,var_off=(0x2; 0x7c)) R5=Pscalar(umax=40,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c))
52: (b7) r5 = 0                       ; R5_w=0
53: (07) r3 += 1                      ; R3_w=Pscalar(umin=35,umax=75,var_off=(0x3; 0x7c))
; if (*((uint8_t*)(data+i)) == 0 && !found) {
54: (71) r0 = *(u8 *)(r0 +0)
invalid access to packet, off=0 size=1, R0(id=3,off=0,r=0)
R0 offset is outside of the packet
processed 48 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 4 peak_states 4 mark_read 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. First is an off by 1 error in the loop, you need to account for the width of the read in the for loop condition:

```c
#define KBUILD_MODNAME "xdp_nvme_drop"
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/if_vlan.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/ipv6.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>
#include "../common/parsing_helpers.h"

static inline int parse_ipv4(void *data, uint64_t nh_off, void *data_end) {
        struct iphdr *iph = data + nh_off;

        if (data + nh_off + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end)
                return 0;
        return iph->protocol;
}

static inline int parse_ipv6(void *data, uint64_t nh_off, void *data_end) {
        struct ipv6hdr *ip6h = data + nh_off;

        if (data + nh_off + sizeof(struct ipv6hdr) > data_end)
                return 0;
        return ip6h->nexthdr;
}

//static uint64_t zeroes[1024];

SEC("xdp")
int nvme_drop(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
        void* data_end = (void*)(long)ctx->data_end;
        void* data = (void*)(long)ctx->data;
        uint64_t total = data_end-data;
        struct ethhdr *eth = data;
        uint16_t h_proto;
        uint32_t cur = 0;
        struct tcphdr *tcph;
        uint32_t i;
        int nbzeros = 0;
        bool found = 0;
        cur = sizeof(*eth);

        if (data + cur  > data_end)
                return XDP_PASS;

        h_proto = eth->h_proto;
        if (h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP)) {
                h_proto = parse_ipv4(data, cur, data_end);
                cur += sizeof(struct iphdr);
        } else if (h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IPV6)) {
                h_proto = parse_ipv6(data, cur, data_end);
                cur += sizeof(struct ipv6hdr);
        } else {
                return XDP_PASS;
        }

        if (cur > 100)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (h_proto != IPPROTO_TCP)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (data + cur + sizeof(*tcph) > data_end)
                return XDP_PASS;

        tcph = data + cur;
        if (tcph->doff > 10)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (data + cur + tcph->doff * 4 > data_end)
                return XDP_PASS;

        cur += tcph->doff * 4;
        
        if (tcph->dest != 4420)
                return XDP_PASS;

        if (cur > total || cur > 100)
                return XDP_PASS;

        nbzeros = 0;
        for (i = cur; data+i+sizeof(uint8_t) < data_end; i++) {
                if (*((uint8_t*)(data+i)) == 0 && !found) {
                        nbzeros++;
                } else {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                }

        }

        if (found && nbzeros > 50) {
                bpf_printk("found nvme pdu tail seq=%u\n", bpf_ntohs(tcph->seq));
        }
        return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

Once you compile and try the above you will run into the second issue which is the complexity of the code.

> The sequence of 8193 jumps is too complex

That is because the verifier has to check for every possible iteration if the body of the loop is valid. But since `data_end` is a u32 without limits that becomes to much. What we can do to fix that is to set an upper limit for the number of iterations. like:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (data + i + sizeof(uint8_t) >= data_end)
        break;

    if (*((uint8_t*)(data+i)) == 0 && !found) {
        nbzeros++;
    } else {
     found = true;
     break;
    }
}
```

However, due to the way the current program is written I had a hard time modifying it. The verifier tracks which variables have been offset checked and which haven't and the current `data + cur` way of tracking the offset generates code that confuses the verifier. So I took the liberty to rewrite it in such a way that everything passes the verifier:

```c
SEC("xdp")
int nvme_drop(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void *head = data;
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct ipv6hdr *ip6h;
    struct tcphdr *tcph;
    uint16_t h_proto;
    uint8_t *tcp_data;
    int nbzeros = 0;
    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;

    eth = head;
    if ((void *)eth + sizeof(struct ethhdr) >= data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;
    head += sizeof(struct ethhdr);

    h_proto = eth->h_proto;
    switch (h_proto)
    {
    case bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP):
        iph = head;
        if ((void *)iph + sizeof(struct iphdr) >= data_end)
            return XDP_PASS;

        h_proto = iph->protocol;

        head += iph->ihl * 4;

        break;

    case bpf_htons(ETH_P_IPV6):
        ip6h = head;
        if ((void *)ip6h + sizeof(struct ipv6hdr) >= data_end)
            return XDP_PASS;

        h_proto = ip6h->nexthdr;

        head += sizeof(struct ipv6hdr);

        break;

    default:
        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    if (h_proto != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return XDP_PASS;

    tcph = head;
    if ((void *)tcph + sizeof(*tcph) > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;
    head += sizeof(*tcph);

    if (head + tcph->doff * 4 > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;
    head += tcph->doff * 4;

    if (tcph->dest != 4420)
        return XDP_PASS;

    tcp_data = head;

    // 1500 is the typical MTU size
    #define MAX_ITER 1500

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ITER; i++)
    {
        if ((void *)tcp_data + i + 1 >= data_end)
            return XDP_PASS;

        if (tcp_data[i] == 0)
        {
            nbzeros++;
            continue;
        }

        found = true;
        break;
    }

    if (found && nbzeros > 50)
    {
        bpf_printk("found nvme pdu tail seq=%u\n", bpf_ntohs(tcph->seq));
    }

    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

This should be functionally the same. In this case I chose 1500 as the max iteration count since most packets will never reach that size. Though you might need to tune that.